# iTextSharp extract each character and getRectangle

Tags: itext, pdf-extraction

I would like to parse an entire PDF character by character and be able to get the ASCII value, font and the Rectangle of that character on that PDF document which I can later use to save as a bitmap. I tried using PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage but that gives the entire text in the PDF as string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text extraction strategies bundled with iTextSharp (in particular the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` used by default by the `PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage` overload without strategy argument) only allows direct access to the collected plain text, not positions.

### Chris Haas' `MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy`

@Chris Haas in [his old answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23915452/1729265) presents the following extension of the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`

```
public class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy {
    //Hold each coordinate
    public List<RectAndText> myPoints = new List<RectAndText>();

    //Automatically called for each chunk of text in the PDF
    public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        base.RenderText(renderInfo);

        //Get the bounding box for the chunk of text
        var bottomLeft = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
        var topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

        //Create a rectangle from it
        var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
                                                bottomLeft[Vector.I1],
                                                bottomLeft[Vector.I2],
                                                topRight[Vector.I1],
                                                topRight[Vector.I2]
                                                );

        //Add this to our main collection
        this.myPoints.Add(new RectAndText(rect, renderInfo.GetText()));
    }
}
```

which makes use of this helper class

```
//Helper class that stores our rectangle and text
public class RectAndText {
    public iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Rect;
    public String Text;
    public RectAndText(iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, String text) {
        this.Rect = rect;
        this.Text = text;
    }
}
```

This strategy makes the text chunks and their enclosing rectangles available in the public member `List<RectAndText> myPoints` which you can access like this:

```
//Create an instance of our strategy
var t = new MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy();

//Parse page 1 of the document above
using (var r = new PdfReader(testFile)) {
    var ex = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(r, 1, t);
}

//Loop through each chunk found
foreach (var p in t.myPoints) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Found text {0} at {1}x{2}", p.Text, p.Rect.Left, p.Rect.Bottom));
}
```

For your task *to parse an entire PDF character by character and be able to get the ASCII value, font and the Rectangle of that character* only two details are wrong here:

- the text chunks returned like that may contain multiple characters
- the font information is not provided.

Thus, we have to tweak that a bit:

### A new `CharLocationTextExtractionStrategy`

In addition to the `MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy` class the `CharLocationTextExtractionStrategy` splits the input by glyph and also provides the font name:

```
public class CharLocationTextExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
    //Hold each coordinate
    public List<RectAndTextAndFont> myPoints = new List<RectAndTextAndFont>();

    //Automatically called for each chunk of text in the PDF
    public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo wholeRenderInfo)
    {
        base.RenderText(wholeRenderInfo);

        foreach (TextRenderInfo renderInfo in wholeRenderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos())
        {
            //Get the bounding box for the chunk of text
            var bottomLeft = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
            var topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

            //Create a rectangle from it
            var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
                                                    bottomLeft[Vector.I1],
                                                    bottomLeft[Vector.I2],
                                                    topRight[Vector.I1],
                                                    topRight[Vector.I2]
                                                    );

            //Add this to our main collection
            this.myPoints.Add(new RectAndTextAndFont(rect, renderInfo.GetText(), renderInfo.GetFont().PostscriptFontName));
        }
    }
}

//Helper class that stores our rectangle, text, and font
public class RectAndTextAndFont
{
    public iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Rect;
    public String Text;
    public String Font;
    public RectAndTextAndFont(iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, String text, String font)
    {
        this.Rect = rect;
        this.Text = text;
        this.Font = font;
    }
}
```

Using this strategy like this

```
CharLocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new CharLocationTextExtractionStrategy();

using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(testFile))
{
    PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1, strategy);
}

foreach (var p in strategy.myPoints)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("<{0}> in {3} at {1}x{2}", p.Text, p.Rect.Left, p.Rect.Bottom, p.Font));
}
```

you get the information by character and including the font.