# c# itextsharp, locate words not chunks in page with their location for adding sticky notes

Tags: c#, itext

I already read all related StackOverflow and haven't find a decent solution to this. I want to open a PDF, get the text (words) and their coordinates then further, add a sticky note to some of them.

Seems to be mission impossible, I'm stucked.

How come this code will correctly find all words in a page (but not their coordinates)?

```
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        for (int page = 5; page <= 5; page++)
        {
            string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, strategy);

            Console.WriteLine(text);

        }

        //txt = sb.ToString();

    }
```

But this one gets coordinates, but for "chunks" that cannot rely they are in proper order.

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);

    LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx strategy;

    for (int i = 5; i <= 5; i++) // reader.NumberOfPages
    {
        //strategy = parser.ProcessContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
        // new MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy("sample", System.Globalization.CompareOptions.None)
        strategy = parser.ProcessContent(i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx("MCU_MOSI", 0));

        foreach (LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx.ExtendedTextChunk chunk in strategy.m_DocChunks)
        {
            if (chunk.m_text.Trim() == "MCU_MOSI")
                Console.WriteLine("Bingo");  // <-- NEVER HIT
        }


        //Console.WriteLine(strategy.m_SearchResultsList.ToString()); // strategy.GetResultantText() + 



    }
```

This uses a class from this post (little modified by me)
[Getting Coordinates of string using ITextExtractionStrategy and LocationTextExtractionStrategy in Itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909893/getting-coordinates-of-string-using-itextextractionstrategy-and-locationtextextr)

But only finds useless "chunks".

So the question is can with iTextSharp really locate words in page so I can add some sticky notes nearby? Thank you.

Comment: The chunks have position and size information. Thus, you can sort them and infer spaces where required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the chunk.m_text only contains one letter at a time which is why it this will never be true:

```
if (chunk.m_text.Trim() == "MCU_MOSI")
```

What you could do instead is have each chunk text added to a string and see if it contains your text.

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);

    LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx strategy;
    string str = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 5; i <= 5; i++) // reader.NumberOfPages
    {
        strategy = parser.ProcessContent(i, new LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx("MCU_MOSI", 0));
        var x = strategy.m_SearchResultsList;
        foreach (LocationTextExtractionStrategyEx.ExtendedTextChunk chunk in strategy.m_DocChunks)
        {
            str += chunk.m_text;
            if (str.Contains("MCU_MOSI"))
            {
                str = string.Empty;
                Vector location = chunk.m_endLocation;
                Console.WriteLine("Bingo"); 
            }                        
        }
    }
```

Note for the example of the location, I made m_endLocation public.