# Why does the itext5 produce text which is not visible through Acrobat Reader?

Tags: itext

I have a small PDF document which is a cropped version from a larger PDF document. I was surprised to see that itext5 (using custom location strategy) was still re-producing all the text that had been left out after cropping. None of this text is visible through Acrobat reader.

How could I make itext 5 detect and ignore such hidden text?
[Link to PDF with hidden text](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pb397cqUxiXqjVKbtdcieZqJYOixI1ER)

**EDIT 1** - wrong document was hyperlinked

**EDIT 2** - Code snippet attached

```
public class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy : 
LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
  public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
  {
   string text = renderInfo.GetText();
  }
}
```

thanks,
Saurabh

Comment: what do you mean by "re-produce" ?

Comment: The text is still there, even when you open the document in Adobe Acrobat (there is no such thing as Acrobat Reader anymore). Just ask Acrobat to show hidden text, and the text will reappear. Note: this functionality isn't available in Adobe Reader. Since you talk about Acrobat Reader; it's hard to know if you're talking about Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader.

Comment: If you want to extract the text within a certain rectangle (such as the crop box), you need to limit the location that is examined by iText to that rectangle. It depends on the version of iText 5 you are using whether or not that's possible. I'm pretty sure iText 7 supports it. In any case: you're not showing any code, so we can't check which `Strategy` you are using to extract the text.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just realized that I had hyperlinked with the document which was the original and not the cropped. Corrected now.

Comment: public class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
  public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
  {
    string text = renderInfo.GetText();
  }
}

Comment: Coding approach nearly identical to what has been demonstrated in this SFO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909893/getting-coordinates-of-string-using-itextextractionstrategy-and-locationtextextr

Comment: Hi @blagae, By "re-produce" , I meant that the API of itextsharp was emitting text which is not visible at all through Acrobat.   Sample document hyperlinked.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie , I am using **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC** , Version 18.  Thank you.

Comment: Which version of iText are you using (you are using iText 5.x.y, but what are the vlaues of is x and y)? Also: in the code snippet you share in the comments, I don't see you limiting the text extraction strategy to the crop box. That means that you want *all* the content stored in the document, not just the cropped content.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie, You are right. I am using itext 5. You are also right in my understanding that I want all the visible text in the document. When I say visible , I mean text which is visible through **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC**.  I do not want to limit text to any specific area. Just all the visible text.  Thank you.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I'm saying. Part of the content is cropped so that it isn't visible in Adobe Reader. You *need* to limit the text extraction to that area defined by the crop box. Of course; that's impossible when you say you do not want to limit text to any specific area. In other words: what you need is technically possible, but you make it impossible because you do not want what you need. That's a pity. It makes that no one can help you.

Comment: *"I want all the visible text in the document. When I say visible , I mean text which is visible through Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. I do not want to limit text to any specific area. Just all the visible text."* - Then text extraction probably is the wrong approach. Text extraction is more like Ctrl-A Ctrl-C from Adobe Reader and less like reading what there is to see. Text can be invisible for a number of reasons, e.g. drawing white on white, invisible glyphs in a font, text covered by some image, ... Text extraction will extract all those "invisible" text pieces...

Comment: You never answered the question which version of iText 5 you are using.

Comment: Hi @AmedeeVanGasse , iText version is 5.5.12.0.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie, I am happy to use your approach. However, considering the document that I have hyperlinked - how would I know what is are the coordinates of the rectangular region which is actively visible to the user.  The  **GetPageSize** method of **iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader**  class gives me the full page width and height. These are the dimensions of the original document from which I created the cropped version. Obviously, this would once again end up in grabbing all the text - visible and invisible.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @mkl, Thanks for responding. If you refer to the sample document that I have hyperlinked. You will observe that doing a **CTRL+A and CTRL+C**   ends up grabbing only the text that is visible to the human eyes. However, iText will many more blocks of text.

Comment: Indeed, the `GetPageSize()` method returns the `/MediaBox`, but I didn't tell you to look at the `/MediaBox`. I told you to look at the `/CropBox`.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie *"there is no such thing as Acrobat Reader anymore"* - unfortunately Adobe swerves back and forth concerning its naming policy. The very early Reader versions were called "Adobe Acrobat Reader", then for quite a number of versions it was "Adobe Reader", and now it's "Adobe Acrobat Reader" again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the combination of

> I was surprised to see that itext5 (using custom location strategy) was still re-producing all the text that had been left out after cropping.

and of your code snippet

> ```cs
> public class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
> {
>   public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
>   {
>    string text = renderInfo.GetText();
>   }
> }
> ```

I assume that you actually are surprised that in the `RenderText` method of your `MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy` you retrieve `TextRenderInfo` objects for text beyond the crop box.

But exactly that comes naturally! Your `RenderText` method implements that method of the `IRenderListener` interface, and the methods of this interface are called for each matching drawing instruction in the page content, no matter whether their result eventually will be visible or not.

> How could I make itext 5 detect and ignore such hidden text?

You can detect and ignore text outside the crop box fairly easily by checking the text coordinates against the coordinates of the crop box of the current document page.

iText actually contains a filter architecture which allows to exclude text chunks to reach the strategy which don't fulfill some criterion.

If you e.g. currently use your strategy like this:

```cs
MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy();
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1, strategy);
```

you can apply a crop box region filter like this:

```cs
MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy();
FilteredTextRenderListener strategyWithFilter = new FilteredTextRenderListener(strategy,
        new RegionTextRenderFilter(pdfReader.GetCropBox(1)));
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1, strategyWithFilter);
```

---

As an aside:

> I want all the visible text in the document. When I say visible , I mean text which is visible through Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. I do not want to limit text to any specific area. Just all the visible text.

- Text can be invisible for a number of reasons other than being beyond the crop box borders, e.g.

  - it may be drawn in the same color as the background, e.g. white on white,
  - some setting or operation may transform text color and background color to 
    the same color even though they may differ originally,
  - a text rendering mode may be used that doesn't draw anything to start with,
  - the glyphs of the font used for the text may be invisible,
  - the text may be covered by some image,
  - ...

  Text extraction will extract all those "invisible" text pieces.

  (Up to a certain point you can extend your text extraction framework to recognize this, you can find many questions and answers on such extensions here on stack overflow, but there'll always be some case you did not cover.)
- Also text may be only partially covered. E.g. consider the case of the letter 'R' and some white rectangle covering the right leg of the 'R' making it look like 'P'

  Text extraction will return 'R' even though Adobe Reader displays something you recognize as 'P'.
- Fonts may have incomplete or outright wrong information on which Unicode character one of its glyphs corresponds to.

  Text extraction will return a wrong output for text using such a font or probably no output at all.
- Text in a PDF may not be drawn using text drawing instructions but instead using vector graphics like arbitrary forms.

  Text extraction won't extract such "text" at all.
- ...

If these issues are a show stopper for you, text extraction is the wrong technology for you and you should use OCR instead.

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted your answer. Just one last question. In your code snippet , `pdfReader.GetCropBox(1)` , how did you arrive at the argument 1. Could there be more than 1 crop boxes ?

Comment: @Sau Each page can have its own crop box, the `1` you ask about is the page number. It had better match the second parameter of `PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage` which also denotes the page number.