# iTextSharp- Draw Rectangle over text

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

My goal is to draw rectangle over searched text.

I already implemented LocationTextExtractionStrategy class, which is connecting text chunks into sentences (one per each line), and it returns starting location- X and Y.

I was using solution from: [Getting Coordinates of string using ITextExtractionStrategy and LocationTextExtractionStrategy in Itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909893/getting-coordinates-of-string-using-itextextractionstrategy-and-locationtextextr) , and here is what i got so far (below is the code for organizing chunks)

```
  public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        LineSegment segment = renderInfo.GetBaseline();
        if (renderInfo.GetRise() != 0)
        { // remove the rise from the baseline - we do this because the text from a super/subscript render operations should probably be considered as part of the baseline of the text the super/sub is relative to 
            Matrix riseOffsetTransform = new Matrix(0, -renderInfo.GetRise());
            segment = segment.TransformBy(riseOffsetTransform);
        }
        TextChunk tc = new TextChunk(renderInfo.GetText(), tclStrat.CreateLocation(renderInfo, segment));
        locationalResult.Add(tc);
    }

  public IList<TextLocation> GetLocations()
    {

        var filteredTextChunks = filterTextChunks(locationalResult, null);
        filteredTextChunks.Sort();

        TextChunk lastChunk = null;

        var textLocations = new List<TextLocation>();

        foreach (var chunk in filteredTextChunks)
        {

            if (lastChunk == null)
            {
                //initial
                textLocations.Add(new TextLocation
                {
                    Text = chunk.Text,
                     X = chunk.Location.StartLocation[0],
                     Y = chunk.Location.StartLocation[1]
                });

            }
            else
            {
                if (chunk.SameLine(lastChunk))
                {
                    var text = "";
                    // we only insert a blank space if the trailing character of the previous string wasn't a space, and the leading character of the current string isn't a space
                    if (IsChunkAtWordBoundary(chunk, lastChunk) && !StartsWithSpace(chunk.Text) && !EndsWithSpace(lastChunk.Text))
                        text += ' ';

                    text += chunk.Text;

                    textLocations[textLocations.Count - 1].Text += text;

                }
                else
                {

                    textLocations.Add(new TextLocation
                    {
                        Text = chunk.Text,

                        X = chunk.Location.StartLocation[0],
                        Y = chunk.Location.StartLocation[1]
                    });
                }
            }
            lastChunk = chunk;
        }

        //now find the location(s) with the given texts
        return textLocations;

    }
```

When i try to draw a rectangle in cords of text, it isnt even close to it. Im drawing rectangle like that:

```
PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageNumber);
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(leftLowerX, leftLowerY, upperRightX, upperRightY);//pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(x);
rectangle.BackgroundColor = color;
content.Rectangle(rectangle);
```

Comment: Please share an example PDF you experience the issue with.

Comment: [PDF Example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DU2fbncr9JvuwrFr1mFIskN8oXYydaMg)
Lets look at page 21.

Comment: Please set `pdfStamper.RotateContents = false` after instantiating the stamper. Your sample PDF has rotated pages. In this case iText tries to help you by using a different coordinate system when drawing. As the text extraction coordinate system remains unchanged, though, using extracted coordinates to draw something fails for rotated pages. The above setting disables this setting.

Comment: Your knowledge is awesome, it works.
Thank you for simple and good  solution!

Comment: I'll make that an actual answer you can accept.

Comment: can i accept your comment in some way, or you have to post an 'Answer' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set

```
pdfStamper.RotateContents = false;
```

after instantiating the stamper.

Your sample PDF has rotated pages. In this case iText 5.x by default tries to assist you by interpreting coordinates you give in drawing instructions in a different, rotated coordinate system. As the text extraction coordinate system remains unchanged, though, using extracted coordinates to draw something fails for rotated pages. The above setting disables this assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use `iText7` and `pdfSweep` it literally has a function that does this.

```
RegexBasedCleanupStrategy st = new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy("the_word_to_highlight");

PdfAutoSweep sweep = new PdfAutoSweep(st);

PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputfile)); 
sweep.highlight(pdfDocument);
pdfDocument.close();
```

That will highlight the words you're looking for.
Of course you can do much more, with some minor configuration.

Comment: What about license, can i use itext7 for educational purposes ?

Comment: thank you, so can i, for example: remove highlighted text ?

Comment: That's a different question. Please create a different SO question for that. And incentivize people to answer your questions by upvoting and accepting answers.

Comment: It says i need PdfWriter, and when i initialize pdf writer and create PdfDocument with it, its totally empty.
When i try to create PdfDocument with PdfReader and PdfWriter, it says document is in use (firstly created PdfWriter locks file for PdfReader), and i cant highlight any text without PdfWriter.
Have you got solution for that ?

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik Please throw away your code, and start anew from an existing example from the web site. It seems that you are mixing different things that you shouldn't mix. Take a step back, clear your head, start anew. No one can help you with your question, because no one can reproduce the question you post.