# How can I add named destination to a pdf file, on a specific line, that is containing a specific string with itext7

Tags: c#, itext7

How can I add a named destination to a pdf file, on a specific line, that is containing a specific string, with itext7 ?

Comment: @KJ Yes I have looked to the link but If I didin't missunderstood destinations can be set just to bookmarks, outlines or paragraphs. I wanted to read the pdf line by line (with itext7 for example) And when the line conrains a specific string then add the destination to this line. Unfortuntely this is not possible I think.

Comment: @KJ OK now got it. I see now that everything is based on the coordinates. So if I find the string in the line I have to get the coordinates and add the destination to this coordinates. OK got it now.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the exact answer for my question in the following stack overflow entry:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44450490/10802527 adaptation answer to [Getting Coordinates of string using ITextExtractionStrategy and LocationTextExtractionStrategy in Itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909893/getting-coordinates-of-string-using-itextextractionstrategy-and-locationtextextr) by @Amila using https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/LocationTextExtractionStrategy.cs as a basis