# How to return a paragraph that contains a specific word?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to read through a document to look for the occurrences of the word "apple". Once "apple" is found, I need to return the entire paragraph that contains this word. Is there a way to do this in C#? Can this be done at all?

Sure, returning the sentence that contains "apple" is fairly straight-forward, but I am not sure of what needs to be done in order to retrieve an entire paragraph. Do paragraphs have identifiable delimiters that I can use along with a regular expression?

To reiterate:

- An entire **PDF** document needs to be analyzed.
- When the word "apple" is found, return the paragraph that contains it.
- do this for each occurrence of the word "apple".

Comment: Do they have two newlines before and two newlines after with no non-whitespace characters between those lines? If so you could use that as a delimiter.

Comment: What kind of "document"? There's countless varieties.

Comment: @itsme86 Left out the document type without thinking about it. Added to my post that it is a PDF

Comment: I'm not sure on an answer, but the first place I'd look is [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/). It has some pretty cool PDF functionality.

Comment: Related SO Post: [Identify Paragraphs of PDF Files Using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491429/identify-paragraphs-of-pdf-fiiles-using-itextsharp)

Comment: As @itsme86, if you didn't parse the PDF document yet, you can use iTextSharp to do so. However, it wouldn't be a very simple task to retrieve the paragraph directly from the PDF (if that's what you're trying to do). Anyways, [here's a good place to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846653/how-to-get-the-particular-paragraph-in-pdf-file-using-itextsharp-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually sentences are separated by a `space` which is in `Regex` equivalent to `\s` or a `carriage return line feed` (`CRLF`) which is `\r\n`
sometimes a line is also one single `\n`.

Let's assume that paragraphs are separated by two (or more) `CRLF` (or `LF`).
Once we have the paragraphs, we can search for any word that we want inside those paragraphs:

```
   private static ArrayList paragraphs(string entireText)
    {
        char[] sep1 = new char[] { '\r', '\n', '\r', '\n' };
        char[] sep2 = new char[] { '\n', '\n' };

        string[] chunks = entireText.Split(sep1);
        ArrayList paragraphs = new ArrayList();
        foreach (string chunk in chunks)
        {

            string[] paras = chunk.Split(sep2);
            foreach (string paragraph in paras)
                paragraphs.Add(paragraph.Trim());
        }
        return paragraphs;
    }

   public static void Main()
        {
            string entireText = "your_text";
             ArrayList paragraphs = paragraphs(entireText);
            ArrayList containingWordList = new ArrayList();
            foreach (String paragraph : paragraphs){
                if (paragraph.Contains(word)) containingWordList.Add(paragraph);
            }
        }
```